# Anybody knows how to uninstall ROS?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed ros fuerte, but i want it to be replaced by ros electric. so basically i want to uninstall fuerte and install electric version. anybody knows how to do this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35429/anybody-knows-how-to-uninstall-ros?/) by [Seungeun Lee](https://answers.ros.org/users/2501/seungeun-lee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2012-05-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What about

```
sudo apt-get remove ros-electric-*
```

?

---

Originally posted by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) with karma: 2108 on 2012-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) on 2012-09-18**:
I tried that with Fuerte and it worked. I also did sudo apt-get autoremove ros-fuerte-*, which I'm not sure is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You don't need to uninstall ROS. You can install ROS Electric alongside ROS Fuerte, and call the appropriate setup script in your ~/.bashrc (or equivalent) file.

---

Originally posted by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) with karma: 2871 on 2012-05-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Seungeun Lee](https://answers.ros.org/users/2501/seungeun-lee/) on 2012-05-31**:
thanks for the answer Piyush~ within .bashrc file i have "source /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash" "export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/ros_workspace:/opt/ros/fuerte/share:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks" "export ROS_WORKSPACE=~/ros_workspace". Approriate setup will be replacing "fuerte" with "electric"?

**Comment by [Seungeun Lee](https://answers.ros.org/users/2501/seungeun-lee/) on 2012-05-31**:
and just curious.. if i want to uninstall ros for some reason,, how can i uninstall it? is there some sort of installer taking care of uninstalling ros? or should i remove the entire "opt" directory by "rmdir" command?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-06-01**:
See answer from @michikarg

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-06-01**:
Correct environment setup for Fuerte is here: http://ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu#fuerte.2BAC8-Installation.2BAC8-DebEnvironment.Environment_setup

**Comment by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on 2012-06-01**:
@Seungeun Lee: Yes. Instead of "export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/ros_workspace:/opt/ros/fuerte/share:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks" use "export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/ros_workspace:${ROS_PACKAGE_PATH". The setup scripts sets the default package path already. Then you just have to change the first line.